# How to position search box on top

Tags: html, css

I have this search box on my site and i would like to place it on the green line on top. what would be the right css rule?

[image]

this is what i have now.

```
.widget .search-form {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the picture you posted? Also a jsFiddle.net example would help.

Comment: Depending on the HTML you may need to change the DOM order...CSS alone may not be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a problem where your containing element is not wide enough.  I'm not sure what element type `.widget .search-form` is, but I'd specify `display: inline-block` which *may* solve your problem, but likely you'll need to make the parent element larger.  Both `display: inline-block` and `float: right` are subject to word wrap.